# React/Redux duplicated component cannot access actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am creating a react redux site.

I first linked up my alert component which is mapped to redux store and it worked fine and did retrieve data, However when I duplicated this code for another component to work exactly the same I received this error.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fetchPosts' before initialization
```

I have tweaked this code all day to try and get this working.

Initial Component without irrelevant functions (Might make it easier to spot the problem)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPosts, fetchItins } from "../../../actions/postActions";
 


class Alerts extends Component {
  state = {
    showAllAlerts: true,
    showAllIntelligenceAlerts: false,
    showAllTravellers: false,
    currentPage: 1,
    alertsPerPage: 20,

  };
 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          style={{ width: "30%" }}
        >
          ALL{" "}
        </button>
        <button
          style={{ width: "30%" }}
        >
          Intelligence{" "}
        </button>
        <button
          style={{ width: "30%" }}
        >
          Travellers
        </button>
        <br />
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Alerts.propTypes = {
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: state.posts.items,

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Alerts);
```

The duplicated Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPosts, fetchItins } from "../../../actions/postActions";

class Itinerary extends Component {
  state = {
    showAllAlerts: true,
    showAllIntelligenceAlerts: false,
    showAllTravellers: false,
    currentPage: 1,
    alertsPerPage: 20,
  };
  //usiing redux action which is mapped to this compoenent
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  render() {
    {
      console.log(this.props.posts.TravelAlerts);
    }
    {
      console.log(this.props.posts.intelligenceAlerts);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <button style={{ width: "30%" }}>ALL </button>
        <button style={{ width: "30%" }}>Intelligence </button>
        <button style={{ width: "30%" }}>Travellers</button>
        <br />
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Itinerary.propTypes = {
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  // newPost: PropTypes.object
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: state.posts.items,

  // newPost: state.posts.item
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(Itinerary);
```

My store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

Where the store is (Index.js)

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import store from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

Actions

```
import Itinerary from "../components/SideNav/Itinerary/Itinerary";
import { FETCH_POSTS, NEW_POST, FETCH_ITINS } from "./types";

export const fetchPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
  fetch(
    "api/internal/alerts/user-alerts?userId=996D7BD5-C625-5C7E-6A02-7F174D955BF8"
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((posts) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_POSTS,
        payload: posts,
      })
    );
};

export const fetchItins = () => (dispatch) => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((posts) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ITINS,
        payload: posts,
      })
    );
};

export const createPost = (postData) => (dispatch) => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postData),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((post) =>
      dispatch({
        type: NEW_POST,
        payload: post,
      })
    );
};
```

reducer

```
import { FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_ITINS } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  items: {},
  item: {},
  itins: [],
  travelAlerts: [],
  intelligenceAlerts: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload,
        travelAlerts: action.payload.travelAlerts,
        intelligenceAlerts: action.payload.intelligenceAlerts,
      };
    case FETCH_ITINS:
      return {
        ...state,
        itins: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am pretty confused and have lost allot of hours to this problem already.
I do not understand why this would work perfectly in one and then as soon as it is reused it throws that error.

The really confusing part is that this was working the opther day and then out of nowhere it just started launching this error at me.

Any advice could really go a long way here.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `import Itinerary from "../components/SideNav/Itinerary/Itinerary";` component import in actions file? This creates circular dependency between modules.

Comment: I have voted to close as a typo. The question unlikely helps future readers I suppose. BTW you might want to take a look on this plugin if you are using webpack to bundle your code https://github.com/aackerman/circular-dependency-plugin